# OpenANN/PyBrain : sparse input Vectors

Tags: neural-network

Does the OpenANN (or PyBrain or any other open-source scalable) project have support for sparse inputs vectors?For example input vectors represented in libsvm format? I want to build an autoencoder which basically finds a lower dimension representation for sparse high-dimension input vectors (something like a 100,000- dimension vector which has about 100 non-zero values). Is there some other library which would enable me to represent sparse input vectors and hence build an autoencoder for sparse input vectors?